# Is is possible to know that onSnpashot connection couldn't be established because of no/bad internet connection? (WEB SDK)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Context**
User has `document` with multiple `subcollections`. On the initial page load, only one of them is being retrieved and render it into the page.

```
FirebaseDb
  .collection(`users`).doc(userId)
  .collection(collectionName1)
  .onSnapshot(
    ... do logic
  )
```

**Case scenario:**
User clicks `loadMore` and the callback establishes another listener as being described above pointing to an additional subcollection.

```
FirebaseDb
  .collection(`users`).doc(userId)
  .collection(collectionName2)
  .onSnapshot(
    ... do logic
  )
```

But in case of user connection gets very poor or he/she loses/disconnects it and as a result, the snapshot fails to establish a connection or return no data at all.

**Question**
Is it possible for the developer to become aware of that?

I've tried onError callback of the onSnapshot listener but it didn't trigger in the described cases. I know `.get` can be used instead and for the described case, it will fallback to `.catch` cycle, but I was wonder if there is a way to know that using onSnapshot?

P.S: I will also appreciate hearing you handle the case where the web app mostly relies on onSnapshot listeners and handle the cases when the data fetch actually fails and notify a user about that. The reason I rely on listeners because once collections are fetched user can modify any documents from user interface I would like to avoid to request every updated document manually after those changes.

P.S.S: I am using Web SDK (JavaScript)

Comment: Firestore does not offer this.  You can use the Realtime Database API instead, with the assumption that they behave similarly regarding their persistent connections.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Doug, I had a look and it will work for my case. By the way does Firebase creates custom error events that can be listened outside (global listener) and not directly on .catch phase of a particular write/read action?